# How to update file object in django 1.6?

Tags: python, django, file

I would like to update a file object in one of my model called 'message'. After exploring documentation I have found `save` method of file object. **I found that `save` won't override a file instead its creating new file with `_1` at end of file name when same file name is given with different content.**

Can someone point out a way to update file object which overrides existing content when same file name but with different content is given, in django 1.6.

Comment: Show us your code so that answers can be more specific.

Comment: @kroolik I have found a way to resolve it as suggested by Alex.